# Can anyone suggest a mechanism for hemiaminal metal complex to imine complex?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

Can anyone suggest a probable reason for this conversion? This seems like a simple conversion from hemiaminal to imine. 
For secondary amine this kind of conversion might be possible by [image]

but in the case of tertiary amine how can something like this form? Is there a chance of removal of RCH2OH?
The metal here is copper(II). Is it possible that the metal has some role to play?

Comment: I think you have to consider the influence of the metal. This cannot be compared to a simple hemiaminal to imine because of the electrons donated to the metal-N complex

Comment: The metal used here is copper.

Comment: I think the electron donation to copper would weaken the N-H bond and make a proton shift from N to O easier. Once that occurs the loss of water is highly favoured because of the driving force of conjugation of the C=N with the aromatic ring

Comment: what about the first case? the nitrogen is tertiary there? this might be the case for secondary amine where there is a presence of N-H bond.

Comment: I think a similar weakening of the C-N bond is reasonable

Comment: Should that result in the removal of an alcohol? I still can't think of a proper mechanism.

Comment: A fairly similar copper complex is discussed in http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/asia.201500889, take a look, probably there is something relevant (or not, I didn't dive deep).